# MSSQL for ordering by String - a1,a10,a2,a3 etc instead of a1,a2,a3,a10

Tags: sql-server

When I use MSSQL Query to sort the name...
Query: Select name from dto.test sort by name asc

I get a1,a10,a2,a3 instead of **a1,a2,a3,a10**

Does anyone know what Query alteration need to done to the specific order of **a1,a2,a3,a10**

Comment: Ideally, fix your design. If you want the values sorted by the numerical value, store the numerical part in a separate column using a numerical data type. In strings `'10'` *is* less than `'2'`, so the ordering is correct.

Comment: @Larnu is there any way to achieve in data type of string consider this column as a barcode AAA1, AAA101, AAA2

Comment: Like I said, fixing your design would be the "best" solution.

Comment: Otherwise you'll need to split the value into separate parts (the alpha and the numerical parts) in your query and then order on that. I *hope* you don't have values like `'a10a'`.

Comment: You need to fix your design. Strings are strings, not numbers. `a2` always comes before `a10`. What you ask is a **very** strong indication that you actually need two separate columns. You could split the string and cast the second part to an int but that wouldn't use any indexes and result in a *very* expensive sort

Comment: Found the solution -> 
Select name from dto.test order by LEFT(lower(name),PATINDEX('%[^ 0-9a-z]%',lower(name))+1)

How to use PATINDEX in jooq query formation

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the below code as part of Query Tweak. It is basic to split the number from string to achieve your result.

```
Declare @Sampletable as Table (Col1 varchar(5))

insert into @Sampletable
(Col1)
values ('a1'),('a10'),('a2'),('a3')


;With Cte
as
(
select Col1,Cast( SUBSTRING(Col1, 2, len(Col1)) as int) as Rnk
from @Sampletable
)
Select Col1 from Cte
order by Rnk asc
```